# Using add_rewrite_rule in conditional statement using $_SERVER

Tags: rewrite-rules

I am currently trying to create new rewrite rules for some taxonomies on a website and I encountered a problem that I just can't understand.

The rewrite rule works perfectly by itself but when I put it in a conditional statement using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` it does not work.

What baffles me is that if I hardcode the value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in a variable, and use this variable in the conditional statement, the rewrite rule works perfectly.

Here is some examples :

Let's say the current URL is :

> domain.com/apparel/shirt/

In this scenario, the rewrite rule works perfectly :

```
$harcoded_uri = '/apparel/shirt/'; // (same content as $uri);

if (strpos($harcoded_uri, '/apparel/') !== false) {
    $regex = '^apparel/([^/]*)/?$';
    $location = 'index.php?type=$matches[1]';
    $priority = 'top';
    add_rewrite_rule( $regex, $location, $priority );
}
```

In this one, the rewrite rule does not work BUT "foo" is echoed :

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // = /apparel/shirt/  

if (strpos($uri, '/apparel/') !== false) {
    echo "foo";

    $regex = '^apparel/([^/]*)/?$';
    $location = 'index.php?type=$matches[1]';
    $priority = 'top';
    add_rewrite_rule( $regex, $location, $priority );
}
```

Is there a logical reason that when using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` which contains the exact same content as my hardcoded variable the `add_rewrite_rule()` function seems to do nothing?  I also can't figure an other way around.

=== EDIT #1 ===

As Milo pointed out in the comments, what I am trying to do with add_rewrite_rule() is not possible.  I am posting here what I am trying to achieve. If anyone has an other idea, I will gladly take the input since I am now out of idea.

With the get parameters I can access this without any problem :

```
domain.com/apparel/?type=shirt
domain.com/apparel/?type=shirt&brand=nike
domain.com/apparel/?brand=nike
domain.com/apparel/?brand=nike&type=shirt
```

I would like to rewrite the urls to access the same content but with "clean" urls like :

```
domain.com/apparel/shirt/
domain.com/apparel/shirt/nike/
domain.com/apparel/nike/
domain.com/apparel/nike/shirt/
```

I am aware that for SEO reasons (duplicated content) that is not recommended but I have a solution for that.  Keep in mind that this is a really dumbed down example.  The urls could be much longer to access many more taxonomies (ex.:  domain.com/apparel/shirt/nike/blue/small)

Comment: Since it is echoing 'foo' your condition is being met - so the problem lies somewhere inside your `if` statement. I am guessing there may be an issue with both the one that's working and the one that's not - specifically - you are using single quotes ' around `index.php?type=$matches[1]`. When you use single quotes PHP interprets literally so it is seeing dollar sign, matches[1] instead of using the actual variable. Try setting that line to double quotes " and see if that changes anything.

Comment: I just tested and my working example does not work when I use double quotes.  I Might have clue here.

Comment: It could be that your `$regex` variable has a similar problem. If you take out your first scenario completely does the site behave the same way?

Comment: I am pretty sure that is the problem.  I don't have time to test at the moment but I will report here tonight.  Since using double quotes in the working scenario made it stop working, I know that the problem is in relation with that.  Thank you very much for the help, I can't believe I did not spot the use of single quotes in $location ...

Comment: Your whole premise here is flawed. Rewrite rules are cached, you can't add a rule conditionally based on the current request because rules may be flushed on any request.

Comment: Well, this is good to know but now I am out of solution... Look at edit #1 in my original post to see what I am trying to achieve

Comment: single quotes is not a problem because WP's rewrite handling mechanism is handling the interpretation, which is why the rewrite was working with single quotes, you do not want this code to replace matches[1] with the actual value of matches[1] here, you want it to be passed as 'matches[1]' itself, in this line matches has no value because you are defining the rule, not parsing a url.

secondly, you don't need to use a condition, the regex itself only matches urls starting with `apparel/`

Comment: what is this `domain.com/apparel/`? a page, product, or what? can you access it with a query string URL: for example `/?pagename=sample-page` is the same as `/sample-page/`. You're going to need that to construct the rewrite rule. Try dumping the wp_query to find out the arg name.